# Facebook review, vague to no explanation of failure

Tags: facebook, publish-actions

For the last three days, 3 different submissions, I have not been able to pass Facebooks review process. The only feedback I am given is:[image]

I clicked around to see if I could find more details, but there aren't any; as far as I can tell, that's it. At this point I have submitted a support ticket, but thought I'd check in here on SO to see if any others have experienced this vague response.

**UPDATE - 2015-05-25[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VPCg2.png)**
After waiting over the weekend to see if fb would answer my direct support ticket (which I submitted thursday or friday of last week) I came to find that this ticket has just vanished; as if I never submitted it. I know it was there, I was watching it over the weekend. I tried to check it around noon (PST) today and it was gone.

Without any further indication from fb what we're doing wrong, I tried again to submit a review request. I made a few changes to screenshot instructions, added some new information about contacting us if something is wrong (i.e., phone number), and added a few more pieces of information about the publish process. Hoping to hear back from them tomorrow (Tuesday) if not sooner.

**UPDATE - 2015-05-25[2]**
I got a response from one of the support members on the FB dev page pointing out that there is a good chance that I was not viewing 'all' tickets on my fb dev support page. He was right. I found the support ticket there with someone from fb offering to help me get things straightened out tomorrow (Tuesday). Will update here once I get more information.

Comment: I am going through exactly the same experience except I didn't get the additional button saying "contact support" in my submission results.   I posted a question about this in the Facebook Developer Community Forum and was told by a FB rep that they would look into it for me.  I'm still waiting to hear back 2 days later.

Comment: Thanks for responding, @MitchM - Someone has been assigned to the support ticket I submitted and there are several trying to help on the FB dev page (https://www.facebook.com/groups/fbdevelopers). I'll be sure to post any new info here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After my final update above (posted on 5/25/2015) I was later informed by the individual assigned to my support ticket that Facebook had a bug in their system that was preventing my submission from being approved. After waiting it out (about 2 days) they got the bug fixed on their end and this morning my submission was fully approved.

The best solution I can think of is: If you've triple-checked and tested your code and you are still failing the review process and getting no explanation as to why - check in with Facebook support either by submitting a ticket (if you have that option) or by reaching out on their [Facebook Dev](https://www.facebook.com/groups/fbdevelopers) page. It's a closed group but they don't seem strict in any sense about who they approve to join. FB devs moderate the group, so posting your situation along with your App ID seems very helpful.

Thanks to everyone who chimed in on this one, here and on the [fb dev page](https://www.facebook.com/groups/fbdevelopers).

Answer (score 0):

Jimmy (I answered your post on the Developer's group). I found this:

"My app was rejected for 'General Issues'. What does this mean?

The App Review process involves loading your app on each supported platform, logging in with Facebook, and using every Facebook integration that you're requesting in review. This often results in what we call 'general issues.' These are errors or bugs relating to loading your app, logging into your app or the general functionality of your app. This means we weren't able to test the permissions you request in your submission.

Since these are issues that prevent us from reviewing your Facebook functionality, we can't comment in detail about how your app uses the Facebook functionality you've submitted for review. Because of this, we reject with 'General Issues' and provide feedback about this on each platform.

If you receive a 'General Issues' rejection, please carefully read all of the feedback. Each platform will receive individual feedback that should explain what issues were experienced in review."

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/review/faqs#scores_achievements

Comment: Thanks Lucas. I responded to you in the FB dev group, but will also respond here for completeness: As mentioned in your post above, General Issues rejections usually come along with feedback pertaining specifically to what and why for each platform. This was not included here. The only feedback I got is what you see above in the screenshot.